# OpenVAS: CLI Vulnerability Scanning [CentOS]

Tags: security, centos, port-scanning, nessus, openvas

I have been trying to figure out how I can execute tasks from the command line with OpenVAS (without any interactions with their web gui)

I've tried running this command:

`omp --port=9392 --host=<IP> --username=admin --password=admin --xml "<get_results/>"`

And it just stalls there, appearing to do nothing. No output, nothing.

After looking around, apparently `omp` is deprecated and people have said to switch to `gvm-cli` found [here](https://github.com/greenbone/gvm-tools).

After switching to `gvm-cli`, I ran the following command, and got this error..

```
gvm-cli socket --gmp-username admin --gmp-password admin --xml "<get_results/>"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phillip/py37/bin/gvm-cli", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/phillip/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gvmtools/cli.py", line 92, in main
    gvm.authenticate(args.gmp_username, args.gmp_password)
  File "/home/phillip/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gvm/protocols/gmpv7.py", line 210, in authenticate
    self._send(cmd.to_string())
  File "/home/phillip/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gvm/protocols/base.py", line 62, in _send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/phillip/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gvm/protocols/base.py", line 98, in connect
    self._connection.connect()
  File "/home/phillip/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gvm/connections.py", line 310, in connect
    self._socket.connect(self.path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what else to do. Could someone steer me in the right direction with this?

What I want to eventually end up doing is create an automated scanning system completely from the command line. I want to be able to:

1. Create a new target
2. Create a new task
3. Run the scan

**How can I accomplish this?**

**Extra Info:**

When running `openvas-check-setup --v9` my output is: `It seems like your OpenVAS-9 installation is OK`

OS: CentOS 7

The web gui runs fine, and I executed a task to make sure everything is working ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, and took many hours of scouring the internet..

All that is needed is this:

```
gvm-cli socket --socketpath /var/run/openvasmd.sock ...
```

Note:
The deprecated way to do this is with `--sockpath` which is what I didn't realize nor does it tell you that.

I hope this helps someone down the line!

Answer (score 0):

> Note: The deprecated way to do this is with --sockpath which is what I didn't realize nor does it tell you that

It's deprecated means it's still recognized and you can still use it. It will only be removed in a future version of gvm-tools.